# How do i change my upstart jobs to systemd?

Tags: server, upstart, ftp, vsftpd

```
sudo restart vsftpd
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused**
```

I have been running this command to restart my FTP daemon after I have done few edits, however I have been getting this error message.

I have read online that I can change easily from *systemd* to *Upstart*, but I want to transition the **upstart jobs** to the **systemd**, not the opposite.

Any ideas? Or just a quick solution to this problem would work too.
I'm newbie here.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04